# ios: lldb error when I close app in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, program-entry-point, lldb

In simulator:

(1) Run app - everything runs fine

(2) Minimize app

(3) Double Tap home button

(3) Hold app with mouse until it jiggles

(4) Click red "-" button

(5) lldb error

I think I may not have released all resources correctly. Is this the main cuase or is it a simulator bug?

It breaks here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because that is what it should be doing :)

you are forcing the app to quit while you are still debugging and it detects it as an unexpected crash (which it is actually, as for debugger)

Comment: Ok thank you I though it was a memory management error on my part.

Comment: Also you can test it by creating a new project and testing your scenario on that empty project. It should react in the same way